# In Spring, how do you specify the BindingResult implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to specify the implementing type of BindingResult within a controller.  Is there a way to do that?  At the moment, it appears that Spring must determine the implementing type itself (which happens to be a BeanPropertyBindingResult).  I suspect there is either a configuration that I'm missing somewhere, or I just need to specify the actual type in the Controller's method signature.

Example:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public ModelAndView continue(@ModelAttribute("model") @Valid final T model, final BindingResult results) { ... }
```

Comment: Why do you need a specific implementation of BindingResult?

Comment: I am attempting to extend Spring's ObjectError and FieldError objects in order to include an error level (ie: info, warn, error) for validation messages.  Right now, Spring is determining the BindingResult (which is where I'm adding the errors during validation).  I need to be able to guarantee the implementing type so that the new errors work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom **BindingResult** for what you want to do.  You need to implement a **BindingErrorProcessor** and use it in the **WebDataBinder**.  It is responsible for adding the errors to the **BindingResult** and will allow you to use your custom **Errors** implementation.  Here is how you would use it in your controller...

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {
    ...

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setBindingErrorProcessor(new MyCustomBindingErrorProcessor());
    }
}
```

Mixing binding and validation is bad practice, classes should have a single responsibility.  You should not be doing validation in the BindingResult itself.

Comment: My intent is not to mix binding and errors.  Only that the errors are added to the BindingResult.  Although I know Spring instantiates the BeanPropertyBindingResult automatically, it must do so by default as I haven't set it intentionally.  I was thinking I'd like to intentionally set the implementing class, so that I don't run into problems if Spring decides to instantiate a different class for some unknown (at least to me) reason.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code, setting a BindingResult implementation is not pluggable.  In the DataBinder, it is instantiated in the initBeanPropertyAccess method along with other configuration.  Besides, IMO you still haven't given good reason you need to use a custom implementation.  Is the BindingErrorProcessor sufficient for what you need to do?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I want a custom one either.  I just want to be able to specify which implementation -that implementation can still be the original BeanPropertyBindingResult.  I'm just worried that Spring might choose to instantiate a different implementation on another controller for some reason I'm not aware of.

Comment: As far as I can tell Spring will use the BeanPropertyBindingResult for all web binding.  If you want to write custom a WebDataBinder, WebBindingInitializer and HandlerMethodInvoker, you can choose which BindingResult will get instantiated.  All access should be done through the BindingResult interface anyway so none of this should matter.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add ModelAndView in front of `@ModelAttribute` like:

```
public ModelAndView continue(ModelAndView model, @ModelAttribute("model") ObjectType objectName){
}
```

Comment: How does that affect the BindingResult?